# How can I change so it zooms in on the correct image in javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

**What I want to do is zoom in which is like zooming in on Amazon products**,
Im having some trouble when zooming on mutliple images. When I hover over it I can only zoom in on the original one. So even though I change the image to zoom on, it still keeps the original one. How can I change so it zooms in on the correct image?
by using javaScript without use any library or framework.
**My code is on this link in order to make the problem clear https://github.com/kmemo/slider-with-zooming-multi-image**

thank you*-*

```js
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('myimage');
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var img;
            var slideIndex = 1;
            showSlides(slideIndex);
            
            function plusSlides(n) {
              showSlides(slideIndex += n);
            }

            function currentSlide(n) {
              showSlides(slideIndex = n);
            }
            
            function showSlides(n) {
              var i;
              
              var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
              if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
              if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
              for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                  slides[i].style.display = "none";
              }
              for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
              }
              slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
              dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
              img = images[slideIndex-1];
              imageZoom(img, "myresult");
            }     


/* image zoom */
function imageZoom(img, resultID) {
  var lens, result, cx, cy, details;
  result = document.getElementById(resultID);
  details = document.getElementById('details');
  /*create lens:*/
  lens = document.createElement("DIV");
  lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
  /*insert lens:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(lens, img);
  /*calculate the ratio between result DIV and lens:*/
  cx = result.offsetWidth / lens.offsetWidth;
  cy = result.offsetHeight / lens.offsetHeight;
  /*set background properties for the result DIV:*/
  result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  result.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * cx) + "px " + (img.height * cy) + "px";
  /*execute a function when someone moves the cursor over the image, or the lens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  
  /*initialise and hide lens result*/
  result.style.display = "none";
  /*Reveal and hide on mouseover or out*/
  lens.onmouseover = function(){result.style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector("#details").style.display = 'none';};
  lens.onmouseout = function(){result.style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector("#details").style.display = 'block';};
  
  function moveLens(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    /*calculate the position of the lens:*/
    x = pos.x - (lens.offsetWidth / 2);
    y = pos.y - (lens.offsetHeight / 2);
    /*prevent the lens from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - lens.offsetWidth) {x = img.width - lens.offsetWidth;}
    if (x < 0) {x = 0;}
    if (y > img.height - lens.offsetHeight) {y = img.height - lens.offsetHeight;}
    if (y < 0) {y = 0;}
    /*set the position of the lens:*/
    lens.style.left = x + "px";
    lens.style.top = y + "px";
    /*display what the lens "sees":*/
    result.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (x * cx) + "px -" + (y * cy) + "px";
  }
  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
  }
};
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.col_product{
    height: 500px;
}
.slider_m{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    width: 100%;
}
.product{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.product img{
    height: 24.25%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.product img.active,
.product img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px){
    .row_page{
        height: 1020px;
    }
    .col_product{
        height: 500px;
    }
    .slider_m{
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .product{
        height: 25%;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        order: 2;
        margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    }
    .product img{
        height: 100%;
        width: 24.6%;
        margin: 0 1px 0 1px;
    }
    .preview{
        height: 75% !important;
        order: 1;
        width: 100% !important;
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }
    .preview img{
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
    }
}
.preview{
    height: 100%;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.mySlides{
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.preview img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

/*..................................................*/
.details {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
}
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    .details{
        height: calc(100% - 50px);
        margin-top:50px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:375px){
    .details{
        height: calc(100% - 100px);
        margin-top:30px;
    }
}
.colors  {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.product-title, .price, .sizes, .colors {
    text-transform: UPPERCASE;
    font-weight: bold; 
}

.checked, .price span {
    color: #ff9f1a; 
}

.product-title, .rating, .product-description, .price, .vote, .sizes {
    margin-bottom: 15px; 
}

.product-title {
    margin-top: 0; 
}

.size {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.size:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.color {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.color:first-of-type{
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.add-to-cart, .like{
    background: #ff9f1a;
    padding: 1.2em 1.5em;
    border: none;
    text-transform: UPPERCASE;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease;
    transition: background .3s ease; 
}
.add-to-cart:hover, .like:hover {
    background: #b36800;
    color: #fff; 
}

.not-available {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
}
.not-available:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f00d";
    color: #fff; 
}

.orange {
    background: #ff9f1a; 
}

.green {
    background: #85ad00; 
}

.blue {
    background: #0076ad; 
}

.tooltip-inner {
    padding: 1.3em; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes opacity {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(3);
        transform: scale(3); 
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1); 
    } 
}

@keyframes opacity {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(3);
        transform: scale(3); 
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1); 
    } 
}

/*.............................*/
/*.. image zoom .. */
.img-zoom-lens {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    /*set the size of the lens:*/
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  }

.img-zoom-result {
    height: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    .img-zoom-result{
        height: calc(100% - 50px);
        margin-top:50px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:375px){
    .img-zoom-result{
        height: calc(100% - 100px);
        margin-top:30px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

<!-- Bootstrap css -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Fontawesome css -->
<link href="css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- css style -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title> my web site</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="product-page my-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row row_page">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col_product">
          <div class="slider_m">
            <div class="product">
              <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="demo cursor" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/200" class="demo cursor" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="">
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" class="demo cursor" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="">
              <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" class="demo cursor" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="preview">
              <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="myimage">
              </div>
              <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/200" class="myimage">
              </div>
              <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" class="myimage">
              </div>
              <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" class="myimage">
              </div>
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col_product">
          <div id="myresult" class="img-zoom-result"></div>
          <div class="details" id="details">
            <h3 class="product-title">men's shoes fashion</h3>
                        <div class="rating">
                            <div class="stars">
                                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                            </div>
                            <span class="review-no">41 reviews</span>
                        </div>
            <p class="product-description">Suspendisse quos? Tempus cras iure temporibus? Eu laudantium cubilia sem sem! Repudiandae et! Massa senectus enim minim sociosqu delectus posuere.</p>
                        <h4 class="price">current price: <span>$180</span></h4>
                        <p class="vote"><strong>91%</strong> of buyers enjoyed this product! <strong>(87 votes)</strong></p>
                        <h5 class="sizes">sizes:
                            <span class="size" data-toggle="tooltip" title="small">s</span>
                            <span class="size" data-toggle="tooltip" title="medium">m</span>
                            <span class="size" data-toggle="tooltip" title="large">l</span>
                            <span class="size" data-toggle="tooltip" title="xtra large">xl</span>
                        </h5>
            <h5 class="colors">colors:
                            <span class="color orange not-available" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Not In store"></span>
                            <span class="color green"></span>
                            <span class="color blue"></span>
                        </h5>
                        <div class="action">
                            <button class="add-to-cart btn btn-default" type="button">add to cart</button>
                            <button class="like btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></button>
                        </div>
          </div>  
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
<!-- jquery js -->
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<!-- popper js -->
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<!--  bootstrap js -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fontawesome js -->
<script src="js/all.min.js"></script>
<!-- code js -->
<script src="js/main_code.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is what your code looks like when I put it into a JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/mnbL3a1d/ - I need to get proper code that outputs correctly in a testing environment to be able to help.

Comment: @warnakey It doesn't work correctly in your fiddle because you didn't include the bootstrap resource.   I wonder if it has something to do with the lens element not being removed/destroyed. It looks like you're creating a new lens element on every slide change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the image getting stuck on the first image, for me it simply doesn't show the next image image preview you click on. (this includes clicking on the already active image). the zoomed image area is just blank.

I think I've narrowed down where the problem is. If you comment out the following from the zoom out function, I get the correct images to show up in the zoom.

```
result.style.display = "none";
```

So my guess is, display:block isn't working on mouse over or something.

Answer (score 0):

When I checked your code on jsfiddle the only issue I got was a layout issue. Otherwise, when I checked the zoom it worked as intended and the images changed and zoomed appropriately when selected and hovered(albeit the image had strange bounds to hover over it properly). I believe the problem may lie in your js and css file imports since those are the only files that weren't loaded in when I tested, so you should test your code without importing anything.

### Code

[jsfiddle that I tested on](https://jsfiddle.net/bp0ec2xs/)

```css
@charset "utf-8";
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.col_product{
    height: 500px;
}
.slider_m{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    width: 100%;
}
.product{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.product img{
    height: 24.25%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.product img.active,
.product img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px){
    .row_page{
        height: 1020px;
    }
    .col_product{
        height: 500px;
    }
    .slider_m{
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .product{
        height: 25%;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        order: 2;
        margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    }
    .product img{
        height: 100%;
        width: 24.6%;
        margin: 0 1px 0 1px;
    }
    .preview{
        height: 75% !important;
        order: 1;
        width: 100% !important;
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }
    .preview img{
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
    }
}
.preview{
    height: 100%;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.mySlides{
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.preview img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

/*..................................................*/
.details {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
}
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    .details{
        height: calc(100% - 50px);
        margin-top:50px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:375px){
    .details{
        height: calc(100% - 100px);
        margin-top:30px;
    }
}
.colors  {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.product-title, .price, .sizes, .colors {
    text-transform: UPPERCASE;
    font-weight: bold; 
}

.checked, .price span {
    color: #ff9f1a; 
}

.product-title, .rating, .product-description, .price, .vote, .sizes {
    margin-bottom: 15px; 
}

.product-title {
    margin-top: 0; 
}

.size {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.size:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.color {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.color:first-of-type{
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.add-to-cart, .like{
    background: #ff9f1a;
    padding: 1.2em 1.5em;
    border: none;
    text-transform: UPPERCASE;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease;
    transition: background .3s ease; 
}
.add-to-cart:hover, .like:hover {
    background: #b36800;
    color: #fff; 
}

.not-available {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
}
.not-available:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f00d";
    color: #fff; 
}

.orange {
    background: #ff9f1a; 
}

.green {
    background: #85ad00; 
}

.blue {
    background: #0076ad; 
}

.tooltip-inner {
    padding: 1.3em; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes opacity {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(3);
        transform: scale(3); 
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1); 
    } 
}

@keyframes opacity {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(3);
        transform: scale(3); 
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1); 
    } 
}

/*.............................*/
/*.. image zoom .. */
.img-zoom-lens {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    /*set the size of the lens:*/
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  }

.img-zoom-result {
    height: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    .img-zoom-result{
        height: calc(100% - 50px);
        margin-top:50px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:375px){
    .img-zoom-result{
        height: calc(100% - 100px);
        margin-top:30px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
<!-- Bootstrap css -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Fontawesome css -->
<link href="css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- css style -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title> my web site</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="product-page my-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row row_page">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col_product">
          <div class="slider_m">
            <div class="product">
              <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="demo cursor" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/200" class="demo cursor" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="">
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" class="demo cursor" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="">
              <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" class="demo cursor" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="preview">
              <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="myimage">
              </div>
              <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/200" class="myimage">
              </div>
              <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" class="myimage">
              </div>
              <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" class="myimage">
              </div>
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col_product">
          <div id="myresult" class="img-zoom-result"></div>
          <div class="details" id="details">
            <h3 class="product-title">men's shoes fashion</h3>
                        <div class="rating">
                            <div class="stars">
                                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                            </div>
                            <span class="review-no">41 reviews</span>
                        </div>
            <p class="product-description">Suspendisse quos? Tempus cras iure temporibus? Eu laudantium cubilia sem sem! Repudiandae et! Massa senectus enim minim sociosqu delectus posuere.</p>
                        <h4 class="price">current price: <span>$180</span></h4>
                        <p class="vote"><strong>91%</strong> of buyers enjoyed this product! <strong>(87 votes)</strong></p>
                        <h5 class="sizes">sizes:
                            <span class="size" data-toggle="tooltip" title="small">s</span>
                            <span class="size" data-toggle="tooltip" title="medium">m</span>
                            <span class="size" data-toggle="tooltip" title="large">l</span>
                            <span class="size" data-toggle="tooltip" title="xtra large">xl</span>
                        </h5>
            <h5 class="colors">colors:
                            <span class="color orange not-available" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Not In store"></span>
                            <span class="color green"></span>
                            <span class="color blue"></span>
                        </h5>
                        <div class="action">
                            <button class="add-to-cart btn btn-default" type="button">add to cart</button>
                            <button class="like btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></button>
                        </div>
          </div>  
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
<!-- jquery js -->
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<!-- popper js -->
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<!--  bootstrap js -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fontawesome js -->
<script src="js/all.min.js"></script>
<!-- code js -->
<script src="js/main_code.js"></script>

  <script>
  var images = document.getElementsByClassName('myimage');
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var img;
            var slideIndex = 1;
            showSlides(slideIndex);
            
            function plusSlides(n) {
              showSlides(slideIndex += n);
            }

            function currentSlide(n) {
              showSlides(slideIndex = n);
            }
            
            function showSlides(n) {
              var i;
              
              var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
              if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
              if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
              for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                  slides[i].style.display = "none";
              }
              for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
              }
              slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
              dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
              img = images[slideIndex-1];
              imageZoom(img, "myresult");
            }  
            
function imageZoom(img, resultID) {
  var lens, result, cx, cy, details;
  result = document.getElementById(resultID);
  details = document.getElementById('details');
  /*create lens:*/
  lens = document.createElement("DIV");
  lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
  /*insert lens:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(lens, img);
  /*calculate the ratio between result DIV and lens:*/
  cx = result.offsetWidth / lens.offsetWidth;
  cy = result.offsetHeight / lens.offsetHeight;
  /*set background properties for the result DIV:*/
  result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  result.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * cx) + "px " + (img.height * cy) + "px";
  /*execute a function when someone moves the cursor over the image, or the lens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  
  /*initialise and hide lens result*/
  result.style.display = "none";
  /*Reveal and hide on mouseover or out*/
  lens.onmouseover = function(){result.style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector("#details").style.display = 'none';};
  lens.onmouseout = function(){result.style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector("#details").style.display = 'block';};
  
  function moveLens(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    /*calculate the position of the lens:*/
    x = pos.x - (lens.offsetWidth / 2);
    y = pos.y - (lens.offsetHeight / 2);
    /*prevent the lens from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - lens.offsetWidth) {x = img.width - lens.offsetWidth;}
    if (x < 0) {x = 0;}
    if (y > img.height - lens.offsetHeight) {y = img.height - lens.offsetHeight;}
    if (y < 0) {y = 0;}
    /*set the position of the lens:*/
    lens.style.left = x + "px";
    lens.style.top = y + "px";
    /*display what the lens "sees":*/
    result.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (x * cx) + "px -" + (y * cy) + "px";
  }
  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
  }
};
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

No JavaScript is needed, just add the correct view port and let the browser worry about that

```
<meta name='viewport'  content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5, user-scalable=yes, viewport-fit=cover, shrink-to-fit=no' />
```